# Remove characters from server names

Tags: c#

In my code, I explicitly specify server names, but I want to implicitly specify server names. Hence, I would like code to take server names implicitely & remove `\\` & `\n` in them.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd ";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C net view";
char[] delimiterChars = { '\\' };
string input = "\\st1\n,\\st10\n,\\st4\n,\\st5";
List<string> serverNames = input.Split(',').ToList();
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *implicitly*?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you're saying about "dynamic arrays", but I think I get what you're trying to do. Here's some code that will split your input and return a list of all the elements without a leading `\\` or trailing `\n`:

```
List<string> serverNames = input.Split(',')
                                .Select(s => {
                                    if (s.StartsWith(@"\\"))
                                        s = s.Substring(2);
                                    if (s.EndsWith("\n"))
                                        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
                                    return s;
                                 })
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: @KMan: It's not quite *nothing* -- the same user asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307814/how-to-create-dynamic-array-in-c) that included the *something* part.

Comment: Gabe, this would work better if you change the `if (s.StartsWith(@"\\"))` to `if (s.StartsWith("\\"))
` because the escaped double "\\" won't match with the "@" present.

Comment: @Roberto: I'm pretty sure that the OP is actually *trying* to remove "\\" (because he mentions server names), but doesn't realize that he needs it in his `input` definition.

Comment: @Gabe Oh ok..  Well it will work if he is trying to remove literally the "\\"  and not the escaped "\" character.

Comment: @Roberto: This is just test code. In real life the input will be coming from a file, where the double-backslashes won't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

In light of new information as a result of editing your question here is your answer:

```
//Write output while removing `\\` and `\n`
Console.WriteLine(
     string.Join(",", input.Split(',').ToList()
           .Select(serverName => serverName
               .Replace("\\", "")
               .Replace("\n", ""))
           .ToArray()));
```

You could use `Regex.Replace()` regular expressions instead of `.Replace()` to make matching more exact if you need more precise control.

Also, `List` ***is*** a kind of dynamic array, except it is strongly typed.

Further, in your example, you have a char array declared as `delimiterChars` but yet you don't use it anywhere.  If it is not part of the example please don't include it, because it confuses people to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking. But if my guess is correct, this may be what you need

```
string[] serverNames = new string[4];
serverNames[0] = "\\st1";
serverNames[1] = "\\st10";
serverNames[2] = "\\st4";
serverNames[3] = "\\st5";
```

do note that `\n` turns into a `newline` and `\\` turns into a single `\`